# std::underlying_type : Does SFINAE prevent undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, undefined-behavior, sfinae

`std::underlying_type` invokes undefined behavior when used with a non enum type.
But where does the undefined behavior appears?

In this code :

```
template<typename E>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<E>::value, std::underlying_type_t<E>> IntEnum(E e)
{
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<E>>(e);
}
```

I tried to use `std::enable_if` to prevent the user from calling `IntEnum` with non-enum types. But as `enable_if` is evaluated before deciding if the function can be called, its template arguments get evaluated too, including `std::underlying_type_t<E>`. So is this UB if called with a non-enum type? How can i change it?

Comment: BTW, it is not UB, but a compiling error.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type seems to say otherwise, is that an error?

Comment: @AlexandreS. I believe that that is an error. It would only be undefined behaviour if the `Condition` specification for `std::underlying_type` was written as a *Requires* clause, which it isn't. Having undefined behaviour for instantiating a template seems weird.

Comment: @TartanLlama I'm fairly sure it's meant to be a *Requires*, but regardless it would be UB by omission (because the standard doesn't specify any behavior if `T` is not an enum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typename std::underlying_type<E>::type` is evaluated even for non-enum type (and is not SFINAE friendly).

You may use one indirection to delay the evaluation and be SFINAE friendly:

```
template<typename E>
constexpr
typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<E>::value, std::underlying_type<E>>::type
IntEnum(E e)
{
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<E>>(e);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df98755f7ac01e64)

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent compilation with `static_assert`

```
template<typename E>
constexpr auto IntEnum(E e)
{
    static_assert(std::is_enum<E>::value, "E must be an enum");
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<E>>(e);
}
```